How to differentiate INSTANCE's of view in ItemsControl Region PRISM
I am trying to create a configurator In WPF with prism that will ouput XML files based on the data in multiple usercontrol views. The order that they are in matters so I cant fire an event that will make all of the viewmodels write out to the file.
Region Definition
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1"  prism:RegionManager.RegionName="BuildStringContent"/>

I am navigating/injecting views into this region with
          _regionManager.RequestNavigate("BuildStringContent", "NewSimpleCurrentTestForm");

All of this so far works fine. I am able to navigate multiple views into the BuildStringContent Region as expected.
When it comes to trying to save everything is where I am hitting a blank.
I tried this to see how the views present themselves
  var tests = _regionManager.Regions["BuildStringContent"].ActiveViews.ToList();
        foreach ( var test in tests ) 
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(test.ToString());
        }

The output of this is
TestBuilder.BuildStringComponents.Tests.Current.Views.NewSimpleCurrentTestForm
TestBuilder.BuildStringComponents.Tests.Current.Views.NewSimpleCurrentTestForm
TestBuilder.BuildStringComponents.Tests.Current.Views.NewSimpleCurrentTestForm
TestBuilder.BuildStringComponents.Tests.Current.Views.NewSimpleCurrentTestForm

Is there a way to send targeted events to each one? I cant see a way how to tell a difference between the different instances of the same view. Any assistance or reading you suggest would be helpful.

Why do you use regions? If you don't need their very loose coupling and late binding, you could use data binding and the problem disappears, i.e. <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Lines}"/> and foreach (var line in Lines) DoStuff(line);

@Haukinger, How can I change the design? The Views injected into the Region that has the Item control are all custom UserControls. I am not familier with WPF or C# if im being honest.

The question's more if you can change the design than how. What are your constraints? Why is it designed the way it is?

@Haukinger Currently the different User controls are coming from different views as they target different classes. The information that needs to be populated is different for each of the insertable user controls. The reason i had them sergregatted is to be able to have smaller viewmodels rather than one constantly growing viewmodel that ALL of the options will be housed in.
